# Creating List of Dictionaries from a Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [ 
        (1, "google", "1", "search_engine"), 
        (1, "pinterest", "1", "social_media"), 
        (1, "yahoo", "2", "search_engine"),
        (1, "youtube", "2", "social_media")
    ],
    ["id", "social_media", "rank", "types"]
)
```

`df1.show(truncate=False)`

```
+---+------------+----+-------------+
|id |social_media|rank|types        |
+---+------------+----+-------------+
|1  |google      |1   |search_engine|
|1  |pinterest   |1   |social_media |
|1  |yahoo       |2   |search_engine|
|1  |youtube     |2   |social_media |
+---+------------+----+-------------+
```

I want a 2 column output with one as id and the other as list of dictionaries like below:

1, [{'rank'**:1**,'search engine':'google','social media': 'pinterest'},

{'rank'**:2**,'search engine':'yahoo','social media': 'youtube'}]

Closest I got is the following:

```
import pyspark
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1.groupBy("id").agg(
    F.map_from_entries(
        F.collect_list(
            F.struct(F.struct("types", "social_media"), F.struct(F.lit("rank") , "rank")))).alias("key_value")
).show(truncate=False)
```

| id | key_value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {{search_engine, google} -> {rank, 1}, {social_media, pinterest} -> {rank, 1}, {search_engine, yahoo} -> {rank, 2}, {social_media, youtube} -> {rank, 2}} |

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is this

```
df2 = df1.groupBy("id", "rank").agg(F.collect_list(F.struct("types", "social_media")).alias("agg_col"))


# Using MapType 
def map_fn(rank, agg_cols):
    result = {"rank": rank}
    for agg in agg_cols:
        result[agg[0]] = agg[1]
    return result

map_udf = F.udf(map_fn, MapType(StringType(), StringType()))
df2 = df2.withColumn("agg_map", map_udf(df2.rank, df2.agg_col))
df2 = df2.groupBy("id").agg(F.collect_list("agg_map").alias("agg_map_list"))
df2.show(truncate=False)


+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |agg_map_list                                                                                                                   |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[{rank -> 1, search_engine -> google, social_media -> pinterest}, {rank -> 2, search_engine -> yahoo, social_media -> youtube}]|
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Is it possible to get another data frame with 'id' as one column and and the result as another column?

Comment: thats df3 right ?

Comment: agg_map_list attribute in df3 is list of struct, not list of dictionary.

Comment: I am hoping to get the result that you got last as one of the column in data frame with the other being id.

Comment: I have updated the answer to use MapType. But I think you should read up on Spark Dataframes. It makes more sense to have Struct instead of Maps... when dealing with huge datasets.